# why do i find static fields in components instanciated by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, static

This is not an issue but a good/bad practice question.
see the code below...

Why do i see often constants as static (and logger too) in components instanciated by Spring ?

Here is my reasoning (correct?)

1/ Spring instanciate my class as a singleton

2/ so, absolutly useless to have static methods (moreover, autowired fields by Spring are systematically NON STATIC fields

3/ so, static fields are useless because all my methods will be instance methods.

So, ok static constant can be used by instance methods, but is absolutly useless!

```
@Component
public class Fac {

    private static final String ROLE_TARGET = "target";

    @Resource
    private Mapper mapper;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Map<String, Boolean> roles = new HashMap<>();
        roles.put(ROLE_TARGET, Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    //other methods below..

}
```

Comment: I think the answer is twofold here. For one, when defining constants, one tends to define it as `static final`. For another, loggers are normally defined `static final` to use the same logger for all instances of the same class. While you are right and one could remove the `static` in your example, it would break the uniformity of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Constants and other methods as `getLogger` **aren't controlled by Spring**,

So it can be static if it fits your application (and every application has constants) and can work together with Spring

Comment: I think OP's question aimed more on the nature of `static` fields in singletons, which are not  strictly necessary since only one instance of the class exists.

Comment: @turing85 ok, but still singleton may have a bug which allow creation more than once or misuse

Answer (score 1):

1. Nothing prevents you from creating an object on your own. You may want to make this class shared and someone else would create as many instances of your class as they want to, which would produce unnecessary copies of the "constant". You may want to make the bean prototype-scoped.
2. Sometimes, it's handy to ask a class about something (reasonably, of course) without searching for its instances. It may be a general constant (e.g. `Fac.DEFAULT_ROLE`), it may be a utility method (e.g. `mergeTwoFacs(Fac a, Fac b)`). I am making it up, I have no idea what `Fac` is :)
3. Still, someone outside may want to ask how an instance has been created, what the rules are, what the default behaviour is, and other stuff that is not related to any instance. `ROLE_TARGET` looks like a thing always used as an init parameter. Any object will have it. It looks like class-level information. It seems to be a legitimate static field.

I don't see anything wrong with it, even though I don't keep any static members in my beans. It's a matter of style, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some code that assigns some values to your static variables, then JVM executes this code when the class is loaded. It is how Java Language Specification defines it. If you want to keep these variables not assigned, don't initialize them in your code. Or remove these static members from these classes.

Important: It is good that you recognized that having static variables to store the state (not related to loggers etc.) in the beans that are initialized by Spring is not a good idea. If you can change these classes, do that. Remove static variables (related to state; logger etc. don't keep state of your objects and can remain).